# Как убрать анимацию в recyclerview

Tags: android, анимация, recyclerview

Как убрать данную анимацию, когда в recyclerview свайпаешь с самого верхнего края или наоборот - с нижнего(как на скрине зеленая область)?
Вот код из layout

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/course_info_auth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/course_info_authIco">

  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

вот эта строчка и убирает EdgeEffect